# Switch component does not change the state when you click on it in iOS

Tags: ios, codenameone

Currently when you click on a Switch component in iOS it doesn't change the state. It used to work before. You can still change the state by dragging the thumb. In Android it works ok.

Comment: This could be related to this: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3048
Does this happen on the simulator too?

Comment: No, the simulator works ok.

Comment: There seems to have been a regression in recent updates. It should be fixed in the code, I'm not sure if it went into the current cloud deployment but it should be there for the Friday update. Please let us know if it wasn't fixed after the coming update this Friday

Comment: After investigation of the bug, it appears this wasn't a recent regression, but rather a long-standing bug in how the Switch component was implemented.  It is now fixed in Git and will be available in Friday's update.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is now fixed in Git, with this commit:
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/da6896e82899eda7e68166a83104a491e3b15c75

It will be available in this week's update on Friday.